# Jquery lightBox disappear on Button Click in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, lightbox

i am using lightbox in my APS.net Web application.
i am opening a ASPX page in ligh box like this

```
<a href="frmInstructorNotes.aspx?lightbox[width]=900&lightbox[height]=500&lightbox[modal]=true" 
 class="lightbox">Add Instructor Notes</a>
```

on frmInstructor notes there are  some text boxes and a button. when i click button data from text boxes saved in database. but after save lightbox disappear and page frmInstructor.aspx opens in browser.
any solution for that? i am using ajax update panel also on that page.

Comment: Consider adding code that you are using as it is not very clear what exactly you are doing.

Comment: please post the function which is written to save the values in the database. Is it a javascript function? If so then it should return false at the end of the function.

Comment: If it is a server side function written on the page frmInstructroNote.aspx.cs then it will not work. You will have to use javacript function with ajax call to server side function

Comment: it is server side function of <asp:Button> on button click

Comment: @krshekhar how i make ajax call in in javascript?? as i new to ASP.net and didint worked on javascript before. and link u suggest where i can found help ?

Comment: There are different ways of doing this. The beast according to me is use Generic httpHandler and jquery to call httphandler function.

Comment: here is a good example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/283976/CRUD-Create-Read-Update-Delete